# Merging accounts - 4 days, no replies or emails

Tags: support, merge-accounts

I've been trying to merge two of my SO accounts (for personal reasons). I filled in the form (from one account and then the other), but I've received no verification emails. Not sure what usual workflow (not even an automated confirmation email) for this is, but is there any way to get in touch with a moderator or other support who can help me? Is this feature broken in some way?

Comment: Why the downvote? There is NO literature indicating that accounts above a certain rep have to be manually merged. This question/answer may come in handy for someone else! It may appear trivial to some, but  there might be very important reasons some people want this done for their account(s).

Comment: Not my downvote but you sound kind of entitled.  I get it, you've waited 4 days, sometimes these things take longer.  Be patient.

Comment: 4 days for a process someone can think happens automatic? I full support the question.

Comment: “Not sure what the SLA for this is” — me neither, but if they’ve breached it, definitely ask for your money back.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt: having merged my accounts recently, I can say this is not an automated process

Comment: @Ani: if you also have a chat user, you need to request the merge of your chat user independently

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It's not broken. I checked and both of your tickets are in the system (I'll go reply to them soon), but just some things to keep in mind:

- There's only two of us that regularly work through these tickets, and we don't set an SLA mainly because the number of tickets we get in daily fluctuates wildly throughout the year. We can't guarantee we'll get to them all at the same pace because we don't know how many there will be to get to. (E.g. at the time of writing, we have a backlog of 80+ tickets.)
- Neither of us generally looks at the queue over the weekend (one of your requests was sent on a Saturday), so you'll rarely receive a response until during the week.

Most of the time this is a non-issue as we have some automated merge systems in place to remove us from the equation when possible. Your requests were kicked to us because your profile has too much reputation and isn't eligible for the automated system.

Comment: Thanks! I just received the email and the merge is underway.

Comment: Do you send confirmations that the request has been received (or is delayed because of manual intervention required)? A notification might go a long way.

Comment: Just a thought: It would surely be useful if, at the very least, an automated mail was sent stating that the request had been received and would be dealt with in due course? It sounds (to me, at least) the the OP was not whinging that they had had to wait four days, but rather checking (*"is this feature broken..."*) that the request hadn't simply gone into a black hole.

Comment: Should be a feature request @SiHa

Comment: Maybe, @ChristianGollhardt, but one for someone else to make. It's a non-issue for me.

Comment: Maybe just a note on the page where you ask "Note: If your rep is above 2k, the merge has to be done manually" (or whatever the limit is).

Comment: @SiHa We've considered that several times, but we always decide not to. One huge factor is an automated reply doesn't do much if you don't have an SLA attached to it. With an SLA, the email actually serves as a receipt - you can check the timestamp and see how much longer you are expected to wait. Without one, it's mostly just a useless message and all we're doing is changing the question to "is anyone even reading the emails" or "is anyone ever going to reply" because users don't know how long to wait. Moderators were also a factor previously, but we've moved those messages on-site now.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @animuson, it makes sense.